# Replication Conflict tables in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, replication

Due to previous several replications during these years in a database I'm working with, there are several tables with names with this format : ***onflict_AllData_[Tablename]**
which * can be a, b, ...

none of them has any record on that.

I really don't know what they are, and how I can remove them safely? Does it harmful for current replications running currently?

Note: the DB Version is SQL server 2000.

Comment: the only safe way is ask to the owner/developer. anyway if the tables all empty you can take a backup and then drop them all: the path to recover should be quite simple since there is no data involved (beware of triggers, keys, foreign keys, permission...).

Comment: @Paolo thanks, but who is the owner. I guess some of them are created a few months ago by me, during the replications(I had some issues in replication for one of our databases). but I dont create them myself. and I couldnt find anything useful in web.

Comment: To identify the owner you have to ask to colleagues. I don't mean 'the sql user that owns the table', that would be simple, but 'the person who have the knowledge about the database structure'. You have to track down a real person and ask questions. The second option is still valid: take a backup and drop them all.